# use batch file to move files where the file name contains a set value

Tags: file, batch-file, find

I have a group of PDFs and i want a batch file to move all files that have a set value in the name of the file. This value will be stored in a variable and generated by another script. For example, if the file name was "abc123abc.pdf" and you wanted to move all files that had "123" somewhere in the name it would move this file.

Comment: are these files in one directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variable is a called pdf_value and the directory is c:\pdf_dir

```
move *%pdf_value%*.pdf c:\pdf_dir
```